# Sitecore Powershell Script to find publish history for a particular date

Tags: powershell-extensions

Is it possible find all the items published on a given date along with Published user , published Date and time using sitecore powershell ?

Comment: As far as I know, no. Because Sitecore does not keep track of published items. You can achieved this though using the publish:itemProcessed. You’ll need to implement custom code to write it somewhere for example in file or database then query that table to generate a report.

Comment: @HishaamNamooya thanks for the replay , does that mean that is no way to get a list if newly published items ? unless we create a custom class and hook ?

Comment: Yeah that’s right. Once I am connected to my laptop I’ll share the piece of code with more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, OOTB Sitecore does not keep track of published item. However, you can create your own. You can do so by listening the the event `publish:itemProcessed`. Below is a code snippet which you can use to store those data.

```
public void OnItemProcessed(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var itemArgs = args as ItemProcessedEventArgs;

    if (itemArgs != null)
    {
        var publishContext = itemArgs.Context.PublishContext;

        var processedItems = publishContext.ProcessedItems;

        foreach (var processedItem in processedItems)
        {
            var item = Factory.GetDatabase("master").Items.GetItem(new ID(processedItem));

            if (item != null)
            {
                //The Logic to store details about the item.

                //Code is for retrieving the user who launched the publish
                var username = publishContext.PublishOptions.UserName
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

You can store the data within a table and then query it to retrieve the data. You can add it on the Sitecore LaunchPad with a filter of the date range. Then you have a method which will generate the report based on the input.

Once you have the piece of code ready, you need to attach it to the event as shown below.

```
<events timingLevel="custom">
   <event name="publish:itemProcessed">
     <handler type="YourNamespace.ClassName, YourAssembly" method="OnItemProcessed" />
   </event>
</events>
```